# Request a large amount data from freebase - Java

Tags: java, freebase

I tried to request a large amount of data from freebase. But I got error message "HTTP response code: 403". Did anyone have similar problem before?

Here is my code

private static final String service_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread";

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try
    {
        String cursor = "";
        String urlStr_initial = service_url + "?query=" + URLEncoder.encode(getQuery(), "UTF-8") + "&cursor";
        URL url = new URL(urlStr_initial);
        List<Freebase> list = new ArrayList<Freebase>();
        Freebase f_b;
        do
        {
            HttpURLConnection  url_con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            url_con.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76");

            StringBuilder str_builder = new StringBuilder();        
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url_con.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                str_builder.append(line);
            }
            String response = str_builder.toString();
            JSONObject j_object = new JSONObject(response);

            if(j_object.has("result"))
            {
                JSONArray j_array = j_object.getJSONArray("result");
                for(int i = 0; i < j_array.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject j_o = j_array.getJSONObject(i);
                    if(j_o.has("id") == true && j_o.has("name"))
                    {
                        String id = j_o.getString("id");
                        String name = j_o.getString("name");
                        System.out.println("ID: " + id + "   /   Name:" + name);
                        f_b = new Freebase(id, name);
                        if(f_b != null)
                        {
                            list.add(f_b);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Null value in Freebase");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("There is no \"result\" key in JASON object");
            }

            if(j_object.has("cursor"))
            {
                cursor = j_object.get("cursor").toString();
            }
            else
            {
                cursor = "false";
            }

            String urlStr = urlStr_initial + "=" + cursor;
            url = new URL(urlStr);
        }while( !cursor.equalsIgnoreCase("false"));

        if(list != null)
        {
            TextFile tf = new TextFile();
            tf.writeToFile(list);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String getQuery()
{
    return "[{"
            + "\"name\": null,"
            + "\"id\": null,"
            + "\"type\":\"/people/person\","
            + "\"limit\": 500"
            + "}]";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what "large" is, but the API isn't designed for bulk downloads.  You should be using the data dumps for that.

There's usually more detailed error message included with the HTTP response code.  If, for example, it says 403 - Forbidden - API key required, it means you didn't include your API key (I don't see where you include it in your code).  If it says 403 - Forbidden - quota exceeded it means you've exceeded your request quota (you can look on the API console to see how much quota you have remaining).